# What am I doing wrong with this boolean?

Tags: android

```
boolean remindertextup = false;
remindertextup = text.contains("Unavailable");
if (value.contains("yes") && (remindertextup = true)){
    //statement
}
```

But the if statement still works if text does not contain unavailable and value contains yes.

What am am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

P.S.: Eclipse shows the boolean remindertextup to be never used.

Comment: `contains` is case sensitive, so unavailable is different from Unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote in the `if` clause sets `remindertextup` to `true`.  Change it to:

```
(remindertextup == true)
```

Comment: For `boolean` comparison you also can do `remindertextup` for true and `!remindertextup` for false. But that's just developer preference

Comment: No worries.  I can't tell you how many times I've done that myself.

Answer (score 0):

In Java (like C and C++) '=' is an assignment. 
Try

```
if (value.contains("yes") && (remindertextup == true))
{
}
```